# Tuple comparison with ORACLE and SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, oracle-11g-r2, pagination

I am working on cursor based pagination using multiple columns. I need to make a tuple comparison since date might not be a unique value.

When I am using MySQL and PostgreSQL, I can do it like this.

```
WHERE (date, id) < (:date, :id) ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
```

I can't do the same with Oracle and SQL Server. I am wondering how can I do a tuple comparison with those databases.

Comment: It would be helpful if you defined exactly what that operation means (particularly with `null` values if your columns are nullable).  If you can define the logic, there are plenty of folks that can help you implement in SQL Server and/or Oracle.  It may take longer for someone that also knows the exact definition in MySQL.

Comment: "cursor based pagination" do you mean "keyset pagination"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that [this MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than-or-equal) documents the behavior you want

> For row comparisons, (a, b) <= (x, y) is equivalent to:
>
> (a < x) OR ((a = x) AND (b <= y))

Then you should be able to write the query across all four platforms as

```
WHERE date < :date
   OR ((date = :date) and (id < :id)) 
ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, this specific syntax is optimized on SQL Server when operating over an index `(date, id)`

Comment: @Charlieface So wouldn't it be better to avoid `OR` like: `WHERE date <= ? AND NOT (date = ? AND id >= ?) ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC` as suggested [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page)?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral As I said, this *particular* case is optimized in SQL Server, you can see the execution plan in this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c846e55dfbd20d1069f2adf89aa9c06b

Comment: I went with the @HasanCanSaral suggestion. In the link Hasan Can Saral shared, it suggest that MySQL is not optimized for tuple comparison but I believe that issue is fixed in my current MySQL version (5.7.35).

Comment: @HasanCanSaral The two-column version is optimized, but with three columns you need to normalize to have the ands at the top level - otherwise, it's not going to seek.